# How to grep a shell variable to match end of line?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

How can I match a bash variable in the end of the line?

The code below can do that for a number in the end:

```
grep '[0-9]$'
```

But in my case the number is a variable. I was hoping something like

`grep '{$i}$'`

where $i is my variable, would work, but no avail. I've tried with several single/double comma combinations but no sucess so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you tried `grep "$i$"`? The second dollar sign, because it does not precede a valid parameter name, should be treated literally.

Comment: I now realized I had tried `grep "{$i}$"`, which doesn't work, but `grep "$i$"` and `grep "${i}$"` do the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this `grep`:

```
grep "$i\$" file
```

OR:

```
grep $i'$' file
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks! can't vote up any answers yet :P

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `"double quoting"` for variable expansion in shell.. use the following:

```
grep "$i\$" file
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks! can't vote up any answers yet :P

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes to make the $ work as end-of-line. If you want to grep with some variable also, use double and single quotes as below:

grep "$var"'$'